# symfony2 and jquery $.post()

Tags: jquery, symfony

How can I get the post parameters in my symfony2 controller when I use the jquery `$.post()` and `serialize()` functions?

Let's say I have a form like this :

```
<form id="formSuppression" method="post" action="#" name="formSuppression">

<input id="form_raison_0" type="radio" value="0" required="required" name="form[raison]">
<input id="form_raison_1" type="radio" value="1" required="required" name="form[raison]">
<input id="form_raison_2" type="radio" value="2" required="required" name="form[raison]">

<input id="form_annonce" type="hidden" name="form[annonce]" value="113664890">

<input id="btnSupprimer" type="submit" style="float: right" value="Envoyer" name="btnSupprimer">
</form>
```

and the jquery function :

```
$("#formSuppression").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var r = $(this).serialize();        
        var url = $(this).attr("action");       
        $.post(url, {
            a:r, 
           }, function(result){
            alert(resul);
        }, "text");                
    });
```

the controller:

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {                    
               $id = $request->request->get('a');
                ...
```

With that controller I have something like : `form%5Braison%5D=2&form%5Bannonce%5D=113664890` for the `$id` variable

But I want the values after the "=" sign. How can I do that without using any other PHP functions like explode, substring...in the controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in params argument of jquery post method, don't use {a:r} but only {r}

```
$.post(url, {
        r, 
       }, function(result){
        alert(resul);
    }, "text");
```

then in the controller

```
$form_value = $request->get("form"); 
$raison = $form_value['raison'];
$annonce = $form_value['annonce'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

$FormData = $$request->request->get('form');

and this $formData contain all your submitted form fields values

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(url, {
        r, 
       }, function(result){
        alert(resul);
    }, "text");
```

change it to

```
$.post(url, {
        r, 
       }, function(result){
        alert(result);
    }, "text");
```